# What is the switching/amplifier component in a 2.4 GHz wifi microwave transmitter

Tags: microwave

I know that it is hard for the transistors that i know to switch at high frequency but the latest microprocessors and microwave transmitting chips use GHz frequency, what is the gain element there (like a transistor, spark gap etc)

Comment: The processors still use silicon transistors since we are unable to economically achieve such high levels of integration on anything but silicon. RF transistor are probably not silicon, at least at the highest speeds.

Comment: from what I've read, INTEL acquired a company that used the picosecond speed of MOSFETS to build up (by summation of various pieces, of various phases and currents) the sinusoids of the RF WiFi signals.